# How do you iterate through a C++ map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

For example:

```
map<string, Person*> family;
family["Bill"] = new Person();
family["Jill"] = new Person();

...

// vvv does not work vvv
for (Person* person: family)
    delete person;
```

I'm trying to do a for-each loop through the map to free the memory for all pointers. This would work for a vector, but not a map. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you type your title into any search engine, you will find plenty of ways

Comment: You look up what the `value_type` of `std::map` is and then use `auto`. That's how you do it.

Comment: Why don't you let your map hold smart pointers rather than raw pointers? Then just clearing the map would cause the smart pointers to release their resources.

Comment: Use smart pointers or store the Person by value and the memory will be released automatically for you.

Comment: What everyone is trying to say, [don't use pointers](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf).

Comment: I see nothing wrong with using pointers. The caveat is making sure you use them *properly*. IMO boost/std pointers appear to create lazier programmers and spawn new programmers to lesser understand the language core. Plus, watching a multi-threaded output from valgrind is absolute murder when you combine STL with (boost) smart pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for( auto const& pair : family )
{
    cout << pair.first << " represented by object at " << (void*)pair.second << "\n";
}
```

Instead of using a loop to delete objects, consider storing the objects directly instead of pointers to dynamically allocated objects.

Here's one way to delete all `Person` objects and remove their map entries:

```
while( not family.empty() )
{
    auto const it = family.begin();
    delete it->first;
    family.erase( it );
}
```

If instead you store `Person` objects (not pointers to dynamically allocated objects) this reduces to

```
family.clear();
```

Comment: Would a simple `delete pair.second;` suffice?

Comment: @CoffeeMaker: As long as that pointer is never referenced later, not even copied. One way to ensure that is remove that map entry. But you can't do that easily in a range based loop iterating over all members.

Comment: @CoffeeMaker: I updated the answer with some more info.